# Tencent International Cloud without PayPal

Tags: paypal, cloud

Is there a way to sign up for Tencent International Cloud without a PayPal account?

Answer (score 0):

Our international service (https://intl.cloud.tencent.com) for customers with registered addresses outside Mainland China currently only accepts PayPal.

We are working to offer additional payment options in the future.